Rail Upgrade to 7.1.4, NoMethodError for jsonb field in Postgres Db
Upgrading a project from Rails 5.2,  made it to 7.1.4 and it's producing an odd issue serializing jsonb.  Given the lack of information I've found, this appears to be an unusual issue.
The error encountered
NoMethodError: NoMethodError
from /home/kevin/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.4/gems/activemodel-7.1.4/lib/active_model/type/value.rb:145:in `as_json'

Backtracking, the errant as_json is called on instances of ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQL::OID::Jsonb
This occurs on field where there is a Hash being serialized is in this shape:
{"name"=>"audited_changes",
 "value_before_type_cast"=>{:this=>[nil, "something"]},
 "type"=>#<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQL::OID::Jsonb:... >,
 "original_attribute"=>
  #<ActiveModel::Attribute::FromDatabase:0x00007faf1e97bf60
   @name="audited_changes",
   @original_attribute=nil,
   @type=#<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQL::OID::Jsonb:... >,
   @value_before_type_cast=nil>}

I've had this with both ActiveModel::Attribute::FromDatabase and ActiveModel::Attribute::FromUser
Any ideas what could cause this and how to resolve it?
Version info:
Ruby 3.3.4
Rails 7.1.4
PG 1.5.7
Audited 5.7.0  (source of this particular error)
Audited::Audit.create(auditable: admin, user: admin, action: 'update', audited_changes: {this: [nil, 'something']}, comment: 'because', version: 1)


Found the problem, it was related to a gem which was monkey-patching active record, where it deviated from the standard serialization path.
